# Drag and drop validation

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm using SwiftUI on macOS, and I am trying to implement drag & dropping **only** folders. To do this, I'm using the [`onDrop`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ondrop(of:delegate:)-6lin8) api, like this:

```
view.onDrop(of: [UTType.fileUrl], delegate: self)

func validateDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
    let itemProviders = info.itemProviders(for: [UTType.fileUrl])
    for provider in itemProviders {
        provider.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { url, error in
            // Make sure url is a folder
        }
    }

    return ...
}
```

I use `validateDrop` to make sure that only folders can be dropped in.

That means loading each item provider, and checking if the url is a folder.

Unfortunately, the `loadObject` api is asynchronous. This means I  have to use something like a semaphore to return back to `validateDrop`.

This could result in deadlocks if `loadObject`'s closure is executed on the same thread as `validateDrop`. In the documentation for [`loadItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemprovider/1403900-loaditem) (very similar), it states

> The block may be executed on a background thread

The keyword is **may** (so it could be executed on the same thread).

Is there any better solution that doesn't require blocking?

Comment: Same for me. Would be interesting to see solutions.
Only thing that I thought of was to track which items got dragged and then validate them without handling the `DropInfo` at all. But that obviously makes part of drag n drop obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Have you `DispatchQueue.main.async`? This is what I use in my code, I have the same flow as you are.

```
@State private var isTargeted: Bool = false // Not used

.onDrop(of: [.fileURL], isTargeted: $isTargeted, perform: { providers in
    dropFile(providers: providers, target: document.id)
    return true
})

private func dropFile(providers: [NSItemProvider], target: String) {
    for item in providers {
        _ = item.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { url, _ in
            if let url = url {
                if url.hasDirectoryPath {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        store.moveFile(id: url.path, newNeigbour: target)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```